# Thymeleaf: Pre-select not working with list of drop-down-boxes

Tags: list, thymeleaf, html-select

In the Controller I build up a list of DTO's and wrap those in a WrappedDtoList.
Code snippet from the Java Controller:

```
...
        model.addAttribute("wrappedDtoList", new WrappedDtoList(
                    Collections.singletonList(new DTO(id, SomeEnum.VAL4)))));
        return "fragment";
...
```

In the HTML I want to build a table (with Thymeleaf) showing each DTO in one row.
In each row I want to have a drop-down box having all possible enum values.
But the enum value from the DTO (in above example VAL4) should be pre-selected.

From "fragment.html"

```
...
            <tr th:each="objectNotUsed, index : ${wrappedDtoList.dtos}">
                <td>
                        <select class="form-control" name="label" id="label">
                            <option th:each="state : ${T(SomeEnum).values()}"
                                    th:value="${state}"
                                    th:selected="${state.label == wrappedDtoList.dtos[__${index.index}__].label}"
                                    th:text="${state.label}"></option>
                        </select>
                </td>
...
```

The drop-down-boxes are there, but nothing is preselected.
Obviously this is not working:

```
th:selected="${state.label == wrappedDtoList.dtos[__${index.index}__].label}"
```

Neither does this:

```
th:selected="${state.label.equals(objectNotUsed.label)}"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If the only issue is the selection test, try:

```
th:selected="${state.label.equals(wrappedDtoList.dtos[__${index.index}__].label)}"
```

(but I have to admit I can't follow the two th:each loops).

Answer (score 0):

I had no success using any variant with `th:selected`.
However, the correct entry from drop down box is selected when...

- using no `th:selected` at all; also no `name` and `id` inside the `select`
- but use `th:field` instead:

```
                        <select class="form-control"
                                th:field="*{wrappedDtoList.dtos[__${index.index}__].label}">
                            <option th:each="state : ${T(SomeEnum).values()}"
                                    th:value="${state.label}"
                                    th:text="${state.label}"></option>
                        </select>
```